# How do I make the following sequential code parallel?

Tags: opencl

I wanted to to make the following kernel code parallel,
  In the code below size of a is n, b and c is 8*n and of d is some value less than n(eg : 3*n/4)

```
j=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  if (a[b[i]]!=a[c[i]])
  {
   d[j]=b[i];
   j++;
  }
 }
```

**Since the number of elements of a and d aren't the same I am facing a problem to give i=get_global_id(0), since by doing this, in some elements of d there would be nothing placed if the 'if'' condition violates...!** So how do I make parallel..?
If not this then, is it possible to delete the "no value" positions of d in the kernel if I store the positions where the values are placed in d in a different array..?

Comment: This can be made parallel; it involves additional resources and processing and performance can be achieved only for very huge values of N.

Comment: so you want to stop if d is filled, or is there some guarantee that there are no more than that many matches?

Comment: create a d array large enough and fill all the values with NAN. Run the Dimension on J; and have the for loop in each kernels, the d array should be created to the max possible value of j,  then compact the d array only with the values not NAN.

Comment: @Chanakya.sun compacting the d array would be anyways sequential which Idont want.. I will make my doubt more clear..

Below is the parallel code which is giving a problem,

i=get_global_id(0);

if (a[b[i]]!=a[c[i]])

        {

             d[i]=b[i];

       }

I will give an eg: of what I exactly want to do.
 
a=[1, 6, 6 ,10 ,6, 20, 16, 20, 16, 20, 1, 6, 10]

b=[1, 2, 4, 6, 8,   9,   11, 13]

c=[3, 4, 6, 7 ,13 ,10   12  9]

Comment: Now here in this case a[b[0]]!=a[c[0]], so condition is satisfied and d[0]=b[0]=1; Now a[b[1]]==a[c[1]], so d[1] is left blank if I execute the parallel code. and a[b[2]]!=a[c[2]], so now d gets filled at its 2nd value i.e. in d[2], whereas I want it to be filled in d[1]...

Comment: Someone Please reply on this...

Comment: make the d array index as a local memory item and access using a local memory barrier fence. Not sure if it works; even if it works the performance will be degraded according to me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is parallel array compaction based on a predicate.

Have a look at techniques described in 
[Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) or in thrust
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html